# How to turn off "Qualifier 'this.' is redundant" warnings in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

In my code I have a lot of `this.` qualifiers (a habit from writing Python code), so I have a lot little orange warning markers in the right hand gutter saying "Qualifier 'this.' is redundant". I don't want to remove the `this.` qualifiers. How can I turn off the orange warning markers?

Comment: It should be possible to open up the ReSharper context menu - click on the pencil thing to the left when the warning is "in focus", or perhaps hit Alt+Enter (?) - and select "Change Inspection Severity..". It should provide several options from Ignore to Error. I believe there is also an inspection option to Require the `this.` explicitly, but I've never felt inclined to look for or enable it. (Such an option would likely be within the main Code Inspection R# options.)

Comment: @user2864740, thanks, the setting was indeed under "Inspection Severity / Redundancies in Code / Redundant 'this.' qualifier". If you would like to write that up, I will accept it as an answer, otherwise I will write it up myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your settings in the Inspection Severity section.  In the C# tab, there is a section called `Redundancies in Code`.  In there is a `Redundant this.' qualifier` setting.  I put mine on 
"Do not show" (gray-colored).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was this removed in R# 9? I can't find it.

Comment: This answer is old now, see pqsk's answer.

Answer (score 19):

For **Resharper 9** it's been moved. Actually I never noticed in Resharper 8, because I use "**this**" for clarity. My problem is that now it's all over the place and it drives me insane. I hope this helps someone, because it took me some time to find this.

[image: Resharper 9 location]

Answer (score 2):

The following is taken from the comment by @user2864740, which the OP found to solve the problem:

> It should be possible to open up the ReSharper context menu - click on
>   the pencil thing to the left when the warning is "in focus", or
>   perhaps hit Alt+Enter (?) - and select "Change Inspection Severity..".
>   It should provide several options from Ignore to Error. I believe
>   there is also an inspection option to Require the this. explicitly,
>   but I've never felt inclined to look for or enable it. (Such an option
>   would likely be within the main Code Inspection R# options.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the ($$$) Resharper, you don't need it to remove the orange warning markers or the lightbulb suggestions.  You can do this within VS 2015: Follow exactly this [set of instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541091/customise-light-bulb-quick-action-rules) in the green-checked answer, but tick the "Qualify member access with 'this' " instead. Click OK, and you'll never see another `this` lightbulb again.

I don't know if this particular configuration is available in other VS versions, but at least you can check your version.

OR, apply the change globally (project-wide or solution-wide) with one click as demonstrated here:

[image: Project-wide removal of <code>this</code> qualifier]

And you'll never see it again in your project.