# Customise "Light Bulb" Quick Action Rules

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The question relates to where can one customise the rule set for the new Visual Studio 2015 Light Bulb or Quick Actions feature.

Specifically I want to disable the one imaged below, for "simplifying" `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

The warning message given is:

> IDE0001 Name can be simplified.

[image: Light bulb feature]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `C#` -> `Code Style`

Then **untick** the following:

> Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword in member access expressions

[image]