# How do I disable Visual Studio 2015 lightbulb when renaming a field?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I've done everything listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31614259/602114, but the lightbulb still pops up whenever I rename a private field, in this case from `db` to `_db`:

[image: lightbulb]

Clicking on the lighbulb suggests performing "rename" refactor action.

[image: refactor suggestion]

However that's exactly what I've just done using ReSharper!  This suggestion pops up every time I rename a field that does not have any references, and when I perform ReSharper refactor action, making it completely redundant.

Is there any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 13):

In order to suppress the VS lightbulb via ReSharper, you need to go to:

ReSharper -> Tools -> Code Inspection (make sure Enable code analysis is checked), and then click the *Do not show VS lightbulb*. Note this will suppress the lightbulb completely (which is redundant anyway if you use R#).

[image]

Comment: Looks like I have it already set. Just tried unchecking and checking it; it seems to suppress lighbulb on the left margin, but not the in-line lighbulb like shown in my question.

Comment: @ikh Did you try restarting VS? Because I don't see that lightbulb at all anymore.

Comment: Just tried restarting VS between checking and unchecking the setting.  The lighbulb is still there. It's not immediately obvious, VS outlines `_db` field shown above and lightbulb pops up only when hovering over the field.

Comment: @ikh Another question, under "Intellisense -> General", did you set ReSharper or Visual Studio?

Comment: @ikh Which version are you using?

Comment: ReSharper 9.2.  Just checked for updates, ReSharper said that there are none.