# VS 2015's Light bulb still shows up?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-2016, visual-studio-lightbulbs

I'm using VS2015 with Resharper 2016.

I've disabled Visual studio bulb at  R# settings :

[image]

Also in here :

[image]

But it still appears when I click on some keywords :

Click on "public"

[image]

Click on "HttpresponseMessage"

[image]

Click on "GetPDF"

[image]

**Question**

How can I *completely* stop the light bulb feature?

[NB - The related answer didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573881/how-do-you-disable-the-light-bulb-in-visual-studio-2015)

Also : 
I've disabled Resharper and now I don't see any light bulb. what's going on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indicator being displayed in the screenshots is ReSharper's "light bulb". The checkbox in the ReSharper options marked "Do not show Visual Studio bulb" will hide Visual Studio's own light bulb feature, so that only ReSharper's is displayed. When this checkbox is cleared, you will sometimes see two separate light bulbs - Visual Studio's and ReSharpers. This checkbox merges the two, pulling Visual Studio's bulb items into ReSharper's menu (which has more features, such as type to search for action).

In order to remove ReSharper's lightbulb as well, you'll need to check the "Do not show" radio button in ReSharper → Options → Editor Appearance. You won't see the lightbulb any more, but using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will still work.

[image: Action Inidcator preferences in ReSharper Options]