# VS2017: Can light bulb be disabled?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm in a metered connection and I can't download stuff freely. VS2017 RC probably is beyond 5GB and that would take almost half of my monthly bandwidth, so sorry for asking this when I could just download it and check it.

My question is... can the "light bulb" be disabled in VS2017? I skipped VS2015 because of it (and autoformatting issues) and I'd like to know if I have a chance with VS2017 or I'll be stuck in VS2012/3 for the next years.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the flag on the top right corner next to the "send feedback" button is meant here. I am unsure if Visual Studio automatically downloads upgrades automatically though. The lightbulb for code improvements shouldn't download things either - for an explaination of the light bulb follow this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872466.aspx

Comment: I just found the following extension for VS2015: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MussiKara.HideSuggestionAndOutliningMargins  Hides the lightbulb (but also some other features). It'd good enough for me in case it will work in VS2017, but at least turns VS2015 from completely unusable to barely usable

Comment: Hi Martin.By the time I wrote the message it was not a duplicate, but I suppose it can be considered a duplicate by now as vs2017 is not RC anymore, and the solution is the same for both vs2015 and vs2017 (which is not the one is marked as accepted in that thread, btw)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly this is a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573881/how-do-you-disable-the-light-bulb-in-visual-studio-2015)

which states that the light bulb is "The light bulb seems to be driven of an Analyzer. these can be manipulated via a Code Analysis Ruleset."

I am unsure if that is really what you are looking for because it seems to be an offline feature that shouldn't take any online traffic (as long you don't click on msdn-links)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a duplicate of that question but for VS2017 instead of VS2015. In fact the answer pointed is not actually disabling the light bulb. btw, I'm not implying that the light bulb downloads data, I meant that I can't unable to download VS2017 just to test if there's a simple switch to disable the annoying bulb :)