# How can I Disable Lightbulb for Fully Qualified Usings in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have:

```
namespace My.Namespace.Admin.Presenter
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.Globalization;

    using My.Framework.Utility;
    using My.Namespace.Core.Business.Admin;
    using My.Namespace.Core.Entities.Admin;

    ...
}
```

In Visual Studio 2015, this is flagged as an improvement by the lightbulb  *IDE0001: Name Can by Simplified* for

- `My.Framework.Utility` to `Framework.Utility`
- `My.Namespace.Core.Business.Admin` to `Core.Business.Admin`
- `My.Namespace.Core.Entities.Admin` to `Core.Entities.Admin`

I don't like the lighbulbs suggestion, how can I turn it off? There doesn't seem to be a global setting for these and clicking the IDE0001 error just performs a [bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=IDE0001%20%20C%23%20Name%20can%20be%20simplified.&form=VSHELP) rather than a dedicated help page.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541091/customise-light-bulb-quick-action-rules) deals with another issue flagged by IDE0001, but not the namespacing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be achieved via creating a **Code Analysis Ruleset**

In project properties select the Code Analysis tab - 
[image]

Then edit a ruleset. The IDE* rules are under the Analyzer `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features`:

[image]

Change IDE0001 to none (or all of them to none), and the rule isn't fired anymore.

It's not granular enough to only get rid of the namespace IDE0001, but does get rid of it along with the rest of IDE0001 "suggestions" which is good enough for my needs.

The created Ruleset can be applied to all projects as needed.

Comment: I also had to restart my Visual Studio instance after modifying my Rule Set.  Thanks!

Comment: In which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (.xproj project)