# How to disable "Light Bulb" Quick Action "simplification" for Nullable<T>?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

For several reasons we prefer `Nullable<Int32>` over `int?`. Wherever possible we prefer Types over keywords - as we do so since C#2 we have a large codebase already using that style.

I recently switched to VS2015 and got the annoying light bulbs all over my code. For `Int32` and other related non-generic types I fixed that by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563565/303290). For `Nullable<T>` however I cannot find the option to disable nagging.

[image: Suggestion to "simplify" <code>Nullable<Int32></code> to <code>Int32?</code>]

How do I disable the `IDE0001 Name can be simplified.` for `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for caring, I ended up disabling bulb and squiggles in R# under `Code Inspection`-`Settings`. R# and CodeRush users may be interested in this [UserVoice suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9139204-option-to-disable-quick-action-squiggles).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your project properties, under the Build tab, in "Errors and warnings", add `IDE0001` to the set of suppressed warnings. I know this isn't really a warning (just a suggestion) but it's the same infrastructure. That removes the suggestion.

Comment: I still have the hope that there is another option. Disabling `IDE0001` would also mean loosing helpful suggestions. As we have ReSharper setting that is already aligned with our style that shouldn't hurt too much.

Comment: @mbx: That's all I've got, I'm afraid. I don't know of any way of configuring it at a more fine-grained level.

Comment: @bitbonk: The OP already refers to that question *in the question*, so I don't think it helps...

Comment: Its worth noting that you will need to unload+reload the project for this to come into effect. Simply building did not get rid of the suggestion...even though its under the 'Build' tab :O

Answer (score 5):

There is a feature-request here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9139204-option-to-disable-quick-action-squiggles

concerning disabling the light-bulb. Please add your votes to this if you agree that it is important.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was finally given for another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36461174/303290):

[*You can disable analyzers on a per-project basis.
To do it, right click on **Project>References>Analyzers** in the **Solution Explorer** and hit **Open Active Rule Set***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36461732/303290)

Here you'd need to disable `IDE0001 Simplify Names` under `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features`.

Additionally you can set `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > predefined type preferences` for `For locals, parameters and members` and `For member access expressions` to `Prefer framework type` and `Refactoring Only` (default). This however is a machine specific config setting.

Comment: That last hint worked better for me thanks! Using VS in Unity projects we dont have much control over the csproj so setting properties in it gets reverted.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to scrap using VS 2017 all together as a result of all of this flashing lightbulb/screwdriver gimmickry. So glad I stumbled on your solution.