# Conditionally Including a NuGet Package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, xamarin-studio

Does anyone have any experience of conditionally including a NuGet package in a build? Ideally it would be good if this could be done based on build configuration so for example package A gets included in a Debug build but package B is used instead in a Release build.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can create a script that takes the build configuration as a parameter and generates the package depending on that (powershell, bat, ...). Then you just need add a task to your build that will run that script to generate the package.

Answer (score 10):

You can edit your .csproj file and include below ItemGroup sections to include any packages conditionally.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
   //Move any package reference here that will only be available in debug mode 
   <PackageReference Include="PackageA" Version="1.0.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
   //Move any package reference here that will only be available in release mode 
   <PackageReference Include="PackageB" Version="1.0.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please Note TargetFramework is the only support condition allowed for PackageReference items. The work around is to use Choose/When. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5895 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803176/conditional-package-reference-in-uwp-project Still have to place within an ItemGroup within the Choose/When