# Conditional package reference in UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I would like to use one NuGet package just for Debug configuration. I [found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) possibility to do it in Visual Studio 2017 if I have a UWP project targeting Creators Update (15063).

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.json" Version="9.0.1" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

But the package is still there also for Release configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' "`?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT no difference

Comment: @JakubKrampl how did you validate the package is still "there" for Release config

Comment: @karann-MSFT I can still see it in references and I can use it in the code. It seems like that only supported condition is [TargetFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#lf-content=182098925:714441902).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Choose>  
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">  
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.json" Version="9.0.1" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

The PackageReference has to be in an ItemGroup than it works.

Comment: instead of using $Configuration can define my own variable? and set it when I build (or uset it..?)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you cannot condition on `Configuration`. Please file a feature ask on [NuGet GitHub repo](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues).

The only supported condition is [TargetFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition)

Comment: Are there any plans to support `$(Configuration)` in package conditionals?

Comment: @kspearrin  Help me understand the scenario here. Why would you want to use one package for debug, and a different one for release?

Comment: The scenario I am currently needing this in calls for creating two different builds for the same project. `build1` (Release) uses a certain feature that requires a nuget package while `specialbuild2` does not use this feature and therefore does not need the nuget package (and in fact cannot even have the dll in it's output). I have created a `Configuration` for `specialbuild2` which uses preprocessor `#if specialbuild2` to remove code while building for `specialbuild2`. During this build I also need to remove the nuget package reference so those dlls are not in the output.

Comment: continued: ... Without the `$(Configuration)` conditional to dynamically remove the nuget package reference I have to manually uninstall the packages before doing `specialbuild2`.

Comment: For example if you use some NuGet package which is needed for test automation and you do not want to keep it inside your release build.

Comment: @kspearrin Please file a feature ask on NuGet GitHub repo - https://github.com/nuget/home/issues

Comment: Someone already did, but it was closed as wont fix. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5895

Comment: can I create my new variable in condition ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Choose/When](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164282.aspx) as a workaround:

```
<Choose>  
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">  
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.json" Version="9.0.1" />
    </When>
</Choose>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works? I get error in VS 2017 Pro "The element <PackageReference> beneath element <When> is unrecognized".