# DB2 connectivity from .NEt core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, db2

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database from .NET core application. My code needs to run in PCF in Linux stack. However the code development and Jenkins build happen on Windows server. My problem is that for DB2 to work properly with .NET core we need to add separate reference for windows and separate reference in Linux. For windows it will be `<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.2.2.100" />
           <PackageReference Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.2.2.100" />`

and for Linux it will be `<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx" Version="1.2.2.100" />
           <PackageReference Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx" Version="1.2.2.100" />`

Now the question is how will I change the DB2 reference during the build time from windows to Linux?
Also I have integration test that needs to be run after the build is completed. Since the Jenkins server is windows, post build, I need to have DB2 windows reference library and just before deployment I need to change it to Linux so that it can be deployed in Linux stack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "Choose/When" around your package references; check out this link:
[choose when](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466850/1186321). Tie your linux references to `$(Configuration)'=='Release'` and your windows references under `$(Configuration)'=='Debug'` or create some new solution configurations if debug/release aren't available.

Comment: No that still does not solve my problem. This leads to more chaos 1) I do not actually test package that I have integration test. What if something worked from windows but failed because of Linux driver 2) I create my DB layer as a NuGet package. So I will be ending up creating two nuget package rather than single one. So I'm pushing this complexity of Choose when complexity to all services that consumes. There could be some 15 odd services. I need to way to block this variance at a wrapper level so that it is transparent to my services