# How do you remove the "fix formatting" dots in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, editor

I updated my VS2019 to the latest 16.11.3 version and these horizontal dots showed up and I have no clue how to disable them. After some searching I found multiple solutions that did not help:

- Edit -> Advanced -> View formatting (this is ticked off - otherwise it shows blue dots like the white ones on the picture below)
- I thought it was my dark mode editor's way of displaying the IDE0055 (fix formatting) error but I did not find the color/font anywhere)
- I've tried a different skin/color theme but the dots remained there

[image: The silly Visual Studio dots]

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for an answer but just stumbled across this.  So in case ya still need it...

One way is to disable analyzers.  Right click project -> Code Analysis -> uncheck Run on live analysis.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2022

also [How do I disable all Roslyn Code Analyzers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461174/how-do-i-disable-all-roslyn-code-analyzers) specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/71678568/5679683

Or just disable that one if you like the rest by hovering on the ...'s and clicking the light bulb -> suppress or configure -> (whatever your preference)