# If a nuget specifies PrivateAssets=all why specify IncludeAssets?

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

The nuget installation pages for development-only packages (e.g. analysers, build tools), typically show this:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Foo" Version="1.2.3">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime;build;native;contentfiles;analyzers;...</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

For such packages, the [`PrivateAssets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) property is always set to `all`.

The `IncludeAssets` property is always specified too. Surely it's redundant?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/vbahh5/what_is_the_meaning_of_the_includeassets_and/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `compile` asset is not listed in `InlcudeAssets`, so in fact it's not the same. The lack of `compile` assets means that if the package contains any dlls under `lib/` or `ref/`, you won't be able to call those APIs, which is a good thing since the package won't be listed as a dependency on your own package.

If you remove that `IncludeAssets` line and call APIs, then anyone using your package (and calls an API which uses your "privateassets=all" package reference), then at runtime a FileNotFoundException will be thrown.

So, having an `IncludeAssets` line that removes `compile` is a good thing, although the same could be achieved by replacing it with `<ExcludeAssets>compile</ExcludeAssets>`, which would have been much clearer.

My gut feeling is that `runtime` should also be excluded, but I have no idea why the people working on NuGet at the time this was implemented made the different decision.

Comment: Thanks. I created a discsussion on the [repo](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/discussions/11998).

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I've wondered this too. If `runtime` should be excluded, shouldn't `native` be too?

Comment: I never paid enough attention to notice that both runtime and native are different entries! I honestly don't understand that decision. I can't quickly think of any scenario of a package with both managed and native runtimes files, but you'd want to exclude only one.